# Some doubts related this Swing MVC implementation. Opening a database connection should be a Controller task?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller, architecture

I am following a Java tutorial related to the implementation of the observer pattern (using Swing) and I have some doubts. My doubts are not related to the observer pattern but about the architecture of this tutorial application (that is based on something like an MVC logic)

So it contains an **Application** class that contains the **main()** method that is the application entry point:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runApp();
            }

        });
    }

    public static void runApp() {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(model);

        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);

        view.setLoginListener(controller);
    }

}
```

As you can see here it is declared a **Model** object (for the data), a **Controller** object that actually simply perform the operation related to the click on a button defined into my view, this is the **View** code:

```
public class Controller implements LoginListener {
    private View view;
    private Model model;

    public Controller(View view, Model model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void loginPerformed(LoginFormEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Login event received: " + event.getName() + "; " + event.getPassword());

    }


}
```

and the **View** object that implement a login form (username and password) with the **JButton okButton** (its click is handled from the previous **Controller** object):

```
public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Model model;
    private JButton okButton;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JPasswordField passField;
    private JPasswordField repeatPassField;

    private LoginListener loginListener;

    public View(Model model) {
        super("MVC Demo");

        this.model = model;

        nameField = new JTextField(10);
        passField = new JPasswordField(10);
        repeatPassField = new JPasswordField(10);
        okButton = new JButton("Create user");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 0, 10);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(new JLabel("Name: "), gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(nameField, gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(new JLabel("Password: "), gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(passField, gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(new JLabel("Repeat password: "), gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(repeatPassField, gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 100;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        add(okButton, gc);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Database db = new Database();
        // Database db = Database.getInstance();

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    Database.getInstance().connect();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(View.this, "Unable to connect to database.",
                            "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                Database.getInstance().disconnect();
            }

        });

        setSize(600, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String password = new String(passField.getPassword());
        String repeat = new String(repeatPassField.getPassword());

        if (password.equals(repeat)) {
            String name = nameField.getText();

            fireLoginEvent(new LoginFormEvent(name, password));
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Passwords do not match.",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoginListener(LoginListener loginListener) {
        this.loginListener = loginListener;
    }

    public void fireLoginEvent(LoginFormEvent event) {
        if (loginListener != null) {
            loginListener.loginPerformed(event);
        }
    }

}
```

It seems that it follow the classic MVC logic but if you look into the **View** class you find this code:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            try {
                Database.getInstance().connect();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(View.this, "Unable to connect to database.",
                        "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            Database.getInstance().disconnect();
        }

    });
```

I am not so into Swing and I don't exactly know what is the **WindowAdapter** object (what is it?) but it seems to me that in this code is add a listener that handle the event related to the main windows opening.

So when the main window of my application is opened the **View** obtain a new connection to the database, when it is closed the connection is colsed.

My doubt is: but is this an antipattern? Opening the connection to the database is not a responsability of the **Controller**?

Tnx

Comment: please whats reason to opening/closing an JDBC connection inside AWT/Swing Listener, is about EDT and Concurency in Swing, it should be invoked from Workers Thread

Comment: Please reference the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, MVC doesn't actually explicitly address persistence.  There are really two schools of thought here.  Bake it into the model, so that the model becomes "self persisting".  Or do it in the controller.

Opening it in the view layer is absolutely not accepted practice.  There is a definite mixing of view/controller logic here.